# Virtual Scrolling / Paging

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, virtual, paging

I was wondering if anyone know of examples out there on how to page a List of data via scrolling. (i.e. like yahoo mail)

Thanks

Comment: any luck? @Dan, I believe he means dynamic loading data... as you scroll contents are loaded, but the scrollbar is already "Full" as in, it doesn't change... just the content gets loaded

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this in a grid [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) can do that. If you want this functionality on the page scroll itself you could use this [one](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/).